# Where do arguments 5 and 6 go in this Microsoft x64 function call?

Tags: disassembly, windows, assembly, x86-64

I'm disassembling a working-as-expected compiled C program (MS/Windows x64, MinGW gcc 10.1.0). In the `main` function, I have the following call which passes 6 arguments to the function `DotProduct`:

```
...
// void** m3 [rbp-0x50] = DotProduct(ptr, ptr2, 3, 2, 2, 3);
  401b9f:   48 8b 55 b8             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x48] // arg2 = m2
  401ba3:   48 8b 45 c0             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x40] // arg1 = m1
  401ba7:   c7 44 24 28 03 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x28],0x3 // arg6 = 3   (+40) <- Δ main rsp
  401bae:   00
  401baf:   c7 44 24 20 02 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x20],0x2 // arg5 = 2   (+32)
  401bb6:   00
  401bb7:   41 b9 02 00 00 00       mov    r9d,0x2                  // arg4 = 2
  401bbd:   41 b8 03 00 00 00       mov    r8d,0x3                  // arg3 = 3
  401bc3:   48 89 c1                mov    rcx,rax                  // arg1 = m1
  401bc6:   e8 34 fc ff ff          call   4017ff <DotProduct>      // DotProduct(m1, m2, 3, 2, 2, 3);
  401bcb:   48 89 45 b0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x50],rax // void** m3 [rbp-0x50] = returned
...
```

Note that `arg5` and `arg6` are placed into `[rsp+0x20]` and `[rsp+0x28]`.

See what happens when DotProduct is called:

```
00000000004017ff <DotProduct>:
  4017ff:   55                      push   rbp
  401800:   53                      push   rbx
  401801:   48 83 ec 48             sub    rsp,0x48       // (-72)
  401805:   48 8d ac 24 80 00 00    lea    rbp,[rsp+0x80] // (-72+128) => (+56)
```

The `rbp` should be at `-0x48+0x80` relative to `main`'s `rsp`, which simplifies to `+0x38` (+56, Δ`main` rsp). The stack pointer decreased 72 bytes, and the base pointer was placed 128 bytes above that (so 56 bytes above the previous stack pointer location). Next, `DotProduct` loads the first four arguments from their registers:

```
  40180d:   48 89 4d e0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rcx
  401811:   48 89 55 e8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdx // (rbp-24) => (+56-24) => (+32) !
  401815:   44 89 45 f0             mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],r8d // (rbp-16) => (+56-16) => (+40) !
  401819:   44 89 4d f8             mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],r9d
```

Wait! How are `rdx` and `r8d` loaded into these memory locations? Aren't they occupied by arguments 5 and 6? What happened?

Right after that, we have this:

```
  40181d:   8b 45 00                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x0]
```

What's going on here? `[rbp+0x0]` hasn't been initialized in this function, so what's in this memory location? Where did arguments 5 and 6 go?

Answer (score 3):

when you are here **4017ff:   55                      push   rbp**

your 5th argument will be available at [rsp+28]
(8 bytes for return address and 20 bytes for HOMEPARAMS (space for saving the 4 args passed via register)

two pushes and one subtract will make your argument no 5  available at
0x28 + 0x8 +0x8 +0x48 = 0x80

so rbp+0 will hold the address of 5th argument after the LEA operation

Answer (score 1):

I've spent many hours (too many for me to admit) trying to figure this out and I just realized what it is, right after hitting submit. `push` instructions implicitly decrease the stack pointer. The call to the function `DotProduct` calls `push` three times; once in the `call` instruction itself, where the return address is implicitly pushed, and twice in the function's prolog, where two quadword registers are explicitly pushed with the `push` instruction. This all automatically decreases `rsp` by 24 bytes, leaving arg5 and arg6 at `[rbp]` and `[rbp+0x8]`. The arguments aren't overwritten.